# Как сделать выборку по определенному признаку через pipe

Tags: angular2, angular, rxjs

Я делаю запрос на сервер для получения объекта. Объект, конечно же `Observable<Object>`. Как мне проверить статус объекта прямо через `.pipe()`?

Я имею ввиду, что мне каким-то образом нужно проверить, если объект имеет состояние `OPEN` или `RESUMED` - на выходе я должен получить `true`.

```
this.objectService.getObjectById(id)).pipe(
    filter(obj => obj.status == Status.OPEN || obj.status == Status.RESUMED))
```

Но на выходе должен выйти не объект, а `boolean` значение, надеюсь, вы поняли мой вопрос

Comment: `map` вместо `ffilter`?

Comment: @overthesanity, уже пробовал, но тогда я получаю просто status, а мне нужно проверить статус на конкретное значение

Comment: не понял? `map(obj => obj.status === Status.OPEN || obj.status === Status.RESUMED)` на выходе всегда будет `boolean`